# Angular 2 - What is window.print in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

In javascript I could do:

```
window.print()
```

To bring up a printer dialog box, but how do you do this in typescript?

Comment: Typescript is a superset of javascript, which means that you (in most cases) do just the same. In this case it's exactly the same. Have you actually tried it and failed?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I tried it use it within a (click) function but it raised an error saying it didn't know what "window" is

Comment: You will not be able to use `window` using an inline `(click)="..."`. Try to put it into a function and call this function into `(click)` bind.

Comment: Ah yes that worked thanks :)

Comment: The `print()` method prints the contents of the current window.

The `print()` method opens the Print Dialog Box, which lets the user to select preferred printing options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did just like that

```
print() {
    // do other stuff...
    window.print();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(window as any).print();
```

use above line if not using typescript 2.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

In the Template file, you can just use the standard JS EventHandler onclick with window.print() for this, like so:

```
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" onclick="window.print()">
  <span class="material-icons">print</span> Print
</button>
```